# Java generic methods: super can't be used?

Tags: java, generics, bounded-wildcard

So I have this method:

```
protected void collectSelectedItems(ListSelectionModel lsm, 
         Collection<? super MyItemClass> result) {
    for (int i : GUI.getSelectionIndices(lsm))
    {
        result.add(getItemByDisplayIndex(i));
    }
}
```

I'd like to return the collection instead of having a void method:

```
protected <T super MyItemClass> Collection<T> 
  collectSelectedItems(ListSelectionModel lsm, Collection<T> result) {
    for (int i : GUI.getSelectionIndices(lsm))
    {
        result.add(getItemByDisplayIndex(i));
    }
    return result;
}
```

with the intent of doing something like this (where `MyItemClass extends MyItemBaseClass`):

```
List<MyItemBaseClass> list = 
   collectSelectedItems(lsm, new ArrayList<MyItemBaseClass>());
```

but I get a syntax error on the `super`:

> Syntax error on token "super", , expected

What gives? Can I fix this?

Comment: What does the error say?

Comment: How do you want to invoke this?

Comment: `Object` is a super of `MyItemClass` so the `Collection` could be a `Collection<Object>`. I don't think you can use `super` here.

Comment: SLaks, Kerrek: just edited answer to address your issues.

Comment: Peter, why not? PECS: I'm passing in a *C*onsumer of MyItemClass, therefore I need to use `super` rather than `extends`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's one link that explains why this is not allowed:

http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TypeParameters.html#FAQ107

It basically just says that use super in type parameters "does not buy you anything", since if this is allowed, erasure will probably just erase it to `Object`, which does not make much sense.

Comment: It "buys you something" if you want to declare your method to take a `Comparator<? super Widget>` though, because a `Comparator<Object>` would be perfectly capable of sorting all subclasses of `Object`. But yeah, for collections, it's almost always the wrong thing to do.

Comment: That's not what the linked page says - it explicitly says that if super were allowed in _method_ declarations, that would help create type-safe generic methods. Right now the example I bumped into is Optional's orElse: it only accepts the same type as the Optional, even though it would often make perfect sense to say
`Optional<Subtype> optional = ...; Supertype result = optional.orElse(supertypeInstance);`

Answer (score 2):

Here are two ideas. The first only returns a generic `Collection`, the second returns the actual `result`-type:

```
public <T, S extends T> Collection<T> ver1(Collection<S> src, Collection<T> dst)
{
    dst.addAll(src);
    return dst;
}

public <U, T extends Collection<U>, S extends U> T ver2(Collection<S> src, T dst)
{
    dst.addAll(src);
    return dst;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

well, I didn't answer my question exactly, but this is an acceptable solution for my problem:

```
protected <T extends Collection<? super MyItemClass>> 
  T collectSelectedItems(ListSelectionModel lsm, T result) {
    for (int i : GUI.getSelectionIndices(lsm))
    {
        result.add(getItemByDisplayIndex(i));
    }
    return result;
}
```