# Generic Lower bounded Method

Tags: java, generics, lower-bound

Let's say I have the following classes `Animal`, `Fish`, and `CatFish`.

`CatFish` extends `Fish` and `Fish` extends `Animal`.

There is a generic class called `MyPets`, which has a type parameter (generic) called `T`, and that will be parameterized with the above classes' objects.

My question is, how do I create a lower bounded method in `D` that will take any objects that is a PARENT class of the `CatFish` class.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8403489/java-generic-methods-super-cant-be-used) may help.

Comment: What's `D`? Is it important, or could this method be declared anywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[You can't](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TypeParameters.html#FAQ107).

TL;DR:

> Type parameters can have several bounds, like in class Box {...} . But a type parameter can have no lower bound, that is, a construct such as class Box {...} is not permitted.  Why not?  The answer is: it is pointless because it would not buy you anything, were it allowed.

Answer (score 1):

[You Can](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TypeParameters.html#FAQ107).

Its just the the use of such Lower Bound Generics is debatable and not encouraged. 
basic use :

```
public void treatAnimalWhichIsCatFishOrSuperType(Animal<? super CatFish> catFishOrParent){
}
```

There are other alternatives when you want to return an instance of a generic type from this method, but you can find that in above link.

Comment: Note that the `? super CatFish` is not precisely a *type parameter* of the method, it's a wildcard for the type parameter of the method's (regular) *parameter*. Lower bounds on type parameters, strictly speaking, aren't allowed, as the other answer states.