# super in Generics T super User defined class not working

Tags: java, generics

I am trying to understand "super" and "extends" with respect to Java Generics. For this, I made following example / code:

```
package com.example.generics;

public class Generics1 {
    
    static <T super Animal> void superDemo() {
        
        
    } 
    
    // "extends" acts like UPPER bound
    // in Hierarchy tree up-to that "class"
    // we can pass on the objects
    
    static <T extends Dog> void  extendsDemoUptoDog(T t) {
        System.out.println("received is --> "+t);
        
    }
    
    static <T extends Cat> void  extendsDemoUptoCat(T t) {
        System.out.println("received is --> "+t);
        
    }
    
    static <T extends Animal> void  extendsDemo(T t) {
        System.out.println("received is --> "+t);
        
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
    
        Dog dog = new Dog();
        Generics1.extendsDemoUptoDog(dog);
        
        Dog dog1 = new Dog1();
        Generics1.extendsDemoUptoDog(dog1);
        
        
        Dog dog2 = new Dog2();
        Generics1.extendsDemoUptoDog(dog2);
        
        
        Cat cat = new Cat();
        Generics1.extendsDemoUptoCat(cat);
        
        Cat1 cat1 = new Cat1();
        Generics1.extendsDemoUptoCat(cat1);
        
        Cat2 cat2 = new Cat2();
        Generics1.extendsDemoUptoCat(cat2);
        
            
        Animal animal = new Animal();
        Generics1.extendsDemo(animal);
        
        
        // Doesn't work ... we have violated the UPPER BOUND
        // even though "animal" is INHERITED from FatherOfAllAnimal
        FatherOfAllAnimal foal = new FatherOfAllAnimal();
        //Generics1.extendsDemo(foal);
        
    }

}

class FatherOfAllAnimal{}
class Animal extends FatherOfAllAnimal{}
class Dog extends Animal {}
class Cat extends Animal {}
class Tiger extends Animal {}
class Lion extends Animal {}

class Dog1 extends Dog{}
class Dog2 extends Dog1{}
class Dog3 extends Dog2{}


class Cat1 extends Cat{}
class Cat2 extends Cat1{}
class Cat3 extends Cat2{}
```

The following is acceptable in method **T extends Animal**, as in method `extendsDemo`.

But why **T super Animal** is not valid, as in method `superDemo`? What is the correct way to express this?

Comment: "But why T super Animal NOT valid" related: [Java generic methods: super can't be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8403489).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `super` generic constraint wouldn't be very useful. If you had a method like this:

```
static <T super Animal> void superDemo(T t) { }
```

you only know that `T` is some super type of `Animal`, which doesn't help very much. You cannot call any of the `Animal`-specific methods on `t`, because `T` could be `Object` (which is a superclass of `Animal`). All you can safely do is call methods declared in `Object`, which isn't much different from

```
static void superDemo(Object o) { }
```

Even if `T` was used in the return type:

```
static <T super Animal> T superDemo() { }
```

You only know that you can at least return an instance of `Animal`, or any of its subclasses, like `Cat`. Again, this isn't much different from:

```
static Animal superDemo() { }
```

That said, a `super` bound is possible when you use it as a wildcard:

```
static void superDemo(List<? super Animal> list) { 
    // this is possible, because of the super bound
    list.add(new Cat());
}
```

This allows the caller to pass any list to which an instance of `Animal`, or any of its subclasses, can be added to the list. e.g. `List<Object>`, `List<LivingThing>`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer; but why does compiler give error ? I agree it may narrow down the choices, why does it even doesn't compile the code?

Comment: @CuriousMind since this is not very useful, why should they spend time, and money to implement this into the compiler at all?