# Compile error in Generics - why not allowed like T extends SomeClass?

Tags: java, generics

I am delving more into Generics, when I feel I know, I get proved otherwise by compiler :-)

Here's source:

```
public class Generics3 {

    <T> void printExtends_compile_error( List<T extends Dog> t) {
        
    }

    void printExtends_correct_syntax( List<? extends Dog> t) {
        
    }

    <T> void printSuper_compile_error(List<T super Dog> t) {
        
    }


    void printSuper_correct_syntax(List<? super Dog> t) {
        
    }

class FatherOfAllAnimal{}
class Animal extends FatherOfAllAnimal{}
class Dog extends Animal {}
class Cat extends Animal {}
class Tiger extends Animal {}
class Lion extends Animal {}

class Dog1 extends Dog{}
class Dog2 extends Dog1{}
class Dog3 extends Dog2{}
```

The methods ending with **_compile_error** are compile errors - why they aren't valid? So, can I used `super` or `extends` only with wild card?

Comment: You can only define `<T>` with class like `class Foo<T>{..}`, or before return type of generic method like `<T> T methodName(arguments){..}`. But at `<T> void printSuper_compile_error(List<T super Dog> t)` you are trying to *define* `<T super Dog>` in *argument* of `printSuper_compile_error` method which is not allowed. Only "defining" *wildcards* `<?>` is allowed there. Now lets wait for someone who will provide relevant specification quotes...

Comment: In fact, I didn't kept <T> before method, the result was same - compilation error.

Comment: List<? extends Dog> also valid in method argument .. this was my understanding, that instead of using ?, we can use like List<T extends Dog)... but it made compiler unhappy.. and makes me feel.. my whole understanding of Generics.. back to square one :-(

Comment: I forgot to mention that you can *use* already defined `<T>` in method arguments like `<T extends Dog>  void printExtends_compile_error( List<T> t) {...}`.

Comment: As for why `<T super Dog>` is not allowed, it is explained in your previous question: [super in Generics T super User defined class not working](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76028395). In short `<T super Dog>` would allow *any* super type of `Dog` *which includes* `java.lang.Object`. But since all classes extend `java.lang.Object` if we write method like `<T super Dog> foo(T argument){..}` it would accept any `Object`, even String since code like `Object obj = "some String"; foo(obj);` would be legal. We would end up creating method like `void foo(Object argument){..}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`printExtends_compile_error` and `printSuper_compile_error` are not valid is because you are trying to use bounded type parameters in a method's parameter declaration, which is not allowed in Java.

In Java, when declaring a bounded type parameter, it must be done at the **class or method level**, and not at the method's parameter level.

So what you want to do is

```java
<T extends Dog> void printExtends_compile_error( List<T> t) {

}
```

However `super` may not be used as type parameter, but only as wildcard. This means, that

```java
<T super Dog> void printSuper_compile_error(List<T> t) {

}
```

will still be invalid.